# OpenGL Directional Lighting + Positioning

Tags: opengl, game-engine, lighting

I'm writing an engine and using Light 0 as the "sun" for the scene. The sun is a directional light.

I setup the scene's Ortho viewpoint, then setup the light to be on the "East" side of the screen (and to the character) (x/y are coordinates of the plane terrain, with a positive z facing the camera and indicating "height" on the terrain -- the scene is also rotated for an isometric view on the x axis).

The light seems to be shining fine "East" of 0,0,0, but as the character moves it does not shift (CenterCamera does a glTranslate3f on the negative of the values provided, such that they can be mapped specifying world coordinates).  Meaning, the further I move to the west, it's ALWAYS dark, with no light.

```
    Graphics.BeginRenderingLayer();
    {
        Video.MapRenderingMode();

        Graphics.BeginLightingLayer( Graphics.AmbientR, Graphics.AmbientG, Graphics.AmbientB, Graphics.DiffuseR, Graphics.DiffuseG, Graphics.DiffuseB, pCenter.X, pCenter.Y, pCenter.Z );
        {
            Graphics.BeginRenderingLayer();
            {
                Graphics.CenterCamera( pCenter.X, pCenter.Y, pCenter.Z );
                RenderMap( pWorld, pCenter, pCoordinate );
            }
            Graphics.EndRenderingLayer();

            Graphics.BeginRenderingLayer();
            {
                Graphics.DrawMan( pCenter );
            }
            Graphics.EndRenderingLayer();
        }
        Graphics.EndLightingLayer();
    }
    Graphics.EndRenderingLayer();
```

Graphics.BeginRenderingLayer = PushMatrix, EndRenderingLayer = PopMatrix Video.MapRenderingMode = Ortho Projection and Scene Rotation/Zoom CenterCamera does a translate to the opposite of the X/Y/Z, such that the character is now centered at X/Y/Z in the middle of the screen.

Any thoughts? Maybe I've confused some of my code here a little?

The lighting code is as follows:

```
    public static void BeginLightingLayer( float pAmbientRed, float pAmbientGreen, float pAmbientBlue, float pDiffuseRed, float pDiffuseGreen, float pDiffuseBlue, float pX, float pY, float pZ )
    {
        Gl.glEnable( Gl.GL_LIGHTING );
        Gl.glEnable( Gl.GL_NORMALIZE );
        Gl.glEnable( Gl.GL_RESCALE_NORMAL );
        Gl.glEnable( Gl.GL_LIGHT0 );

        Gl.glShadeModel( Gl.GL_SMOOTH );

        float[] AmbientLight = new float[4] { pAmbientRed, pAmbientGreen, pAmbientBlue, 1.0f };
        float[] DiffuseLight = new float[4] { pDiffuseRed, pDiffuseGreen, pDiffuseBlue, 1.0f };
        float[] PositionLight = new float[4] { pX + 10.0f, pY, 0, 0.0f };
        //Light position of Direction is 5 to the east of the player.

        Gl.glLightfv( Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight );
        Gl.glLightfv( Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight );
        Gl.glLightfv( Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, PositionLight );

        Gl.glEnable( Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
        Gl.glColorMaterial( Gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, Gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE );
    }
```

Comment: It might help to post your code showing where you set up your lights.

Comment: Edited the original to contain the lighting code.

Comment: Are you calculating and sending normals for each vertex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to provide normals for each surface. What is happening (without normals) is the directional light is essentially shining on everything east of zero, positionally, while everything there has a normal of 0,0,1 (it faces west.)

You do not need to send normals with each vertex as far as I can tell, but rather because GL is a state machine, you need to make sure that whenever the normal changes you change it. So if you're rendering a face on a cube, the 'west' face should have a single call

```
glNormal3i(0,0,1);
glTexCoord..
glVertex3f...
glTexCoord..
etc.
```

In the case of x-y-z aligned rectangular prisms, 'integers' are sufficient. For faces that do not face one of the six cardinal directions, you will need to normalize them. In my experience you only need to normalize the first three points unless the quad is not flat. This is done by finding the normal of the triangle formed by the first three sides in the quad.

There are a few simple tuts on 'Calculating Normals' that I found enlightening.

The second part of this is that since it is a directional light, (W=0) repositioning it with the player position doesn't make sense. Unless the light itself is being emitted from behind the camera and you are rotating an object in front of you (like a model) that you wish to always be front-lit, its position should probably be something like

```
float[] PositionLight = new float[4] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
```

Or, if the GLx direction is being interpreted as the East-West direction (i.e. you initially are facing north/south)

```
float[] PositionLight = new float[4] { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

The concept is that you are calculating the light per-face, and if the light doesn't move and the scene itself is not moving (just the camera moving around the scene) the directional calculation will always remain correct. Provided the normals are accurate, GL can figure out the intensity of light showing on a particular face.

The final thing here is that GL will not automatically handle shadows for you. Basic GL_Light is sufficient for a controlled lighting of a series of convex shapes, so you will have to figure out whether or not a light (such as the sun) should be applied to a face. In some cases this is just taking the solid the face belongs to and seeing if the vector of the sun's light intersects with another solid before reaching the 'sky'.

Look for stuff on lightmaps as well as shadowmapping for this.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can trip up many people is that the position sent to `glLightFv` is translated by the current matrix stack. Thus if you want to have your light set to a specific position in world coordinates, your camera and projection matrices must be set and active on the matrix stack at the time of the `glLightFv` call.